# Jquery - Filtering cascaded list based on class (Seprate list and nested list)

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my sample HTML trying achieve some filtering logic for business functionality. We have a  Complex structure HTML and i just hard coded some sample HTML to make some example out of it

```
<ol class="list_1">
<li class="page_1">one</li>
<li class="page_1">two</li>
<li><span class="ing_page_1">three
</span><ol class="list_2">
<li class="page_1">sub 1</li>
<li class="page__1">sub 2</li>
<li class="page__2">sub 3</li>
</ol>
</li>
<li class="page_2">four</li>
<li class="page_2">five</li>
</ol>
```

Am trying to Filter the list to get below results(DOM Elements).

Query to get DOM elements as results so i can add some attribute for each list

```
List 1 and its pages(List 1 - One, Two , Three , Four , Five)
List 2 and its pages(List 2 - Sub 1,Sub 2 , Sub 3)
```

Class 'ing_page_1' also belongs to page 1 but when i have nested structure i have some special class created with `ing`_ to process some other logic and it is a constant

have added my fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/pjagana/ubk8ngha/6/) with console statements as my filter always result in sub list as well. Any help would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate through all immediate child `li`s and remove non span (or attr*=ing_page) then get the text.

Maybe you can try this:

```js
function getList(parent) {
  var temp = parent + " and its pages (" + parent + " - ";

  $("." + parent + ' > li').each(function() { // Find all immediate li children
    // Create a clone
    var $clone = $(this).clone();
    // remove non-span elements and remove them so only span elements would be left (you can replace this with ':not([class&=ing_page])' or something similar if needed)
    $clone.find(':not(span)').remove();
    // clean the text
    temp += $.trim($clone.text().replace(/\s{2,}/gim, " "));

    if ($(this).is(':not(:last-child)'))
      temp += ", ";
  });

  return temp + ")";
}

console.log(getList('list_1') + "\n" + getList('list_2'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="list_1">
  <li class="page_1">one</li>
  <li class="page_1">two</li>
  <li>
    <span class="ing_page_1">three</span>
    <ol class="list_2">
      <li class="page_1">sub 1</li>
      <li class="page__1">sub 2</li>
      <li class="page__2">sub 3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li class="page_2">four</li>
  <li class="page_2">five</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks. have modified my question to get o/p as DOM Element and not just text